# R repeatedly update dataframe with results from for loop

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I've been searching through possible solutions, and found something that partially works for my application.  I am adding missing data to an existing data frame in "chunks" through a loop. The update has rows that don't exist in the main table.

The problem I am running into is that I need to insert the rows from the second table that don't exist in the first table, and fill in the Value1 column with 0's where the new rows are added.

*(Each SubDF is over 50k rows long, and there can be 50 SubDF's to iterate through per MainDF, resulting in a 2.5mil row MainDF)*

**Current code: (Pardon the loop coding, it's not functional. Just using it for iliustration)**

```
Main_DF
df_list <- c(Sub_DF1, Sub_DF2, SubDF3)

for (i in df_list){

Sub_DF <- i

############## Code in question
setDT(Main_DF)
setDT(Sub_DF)

Main_DF[Sub_DF, 
   on=c("Path1", "Path2","File_Name", "ID"),  
   c("value2") := .(i.value2)] 
###############
}
```

**Various other permutations I have tried:**

```
#
setDT(Main_DF)
setDT(Sub_DF)
setkeyv(Main_DF, c("Path1", "Path2","File_Name", "ID"))
setkeyv(Sub_DF, c("Path1", "Path2","File_Name", "ID"))
Main_DF<- Main_DF[Sub_DF]

#    
Main_DF<- merge(Main_DF, Sub_DF, by = c("Path1", "Path2","File_Name", "ID"), 
all = TRUE)

#
Main_DF[Sub_DF, on=c("Path1", "Path2","File_Name", "ID"),  
           c("Value2") := .(i.Value2)] 

# 
Main_DF[Sub_DF,]

#    
Main_DF<- Main_DF[Sub_DF, on=c("Path1", "Path2","File_Name", "ID")]

#    
Main_DF[Sub_DF, on=.("Path1", "Path2","File_Name", "ID"),  `:=` (Value2= 
i.Value2)] 

#
Main_DF <- merge(Main_DF,Sub_DF,by=c("Path1", "Path2","File_Name", "ID"),all 
=T, fill.NA = 0)
```

**Main DF**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name   ID   Value1
root    home    Sample1     1    1
root    home    Sample1     2    0
root    home    Sample1     7    1
root    home    Sample2     1    0
root    home    Sample2     2    1
root    home    Sample2     3    1
root    home    Sample2     8    1
root    home    Sample3     1    0
root    home    Sample3     2    1
root    home    Sample3     6    1
```

**Sub DF (1st iteration of loop)**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name  ID  Value2
root    home    Sample1    1   5000
root    home    Sample1    2   9000
root    home    Sample1    5   400
root    home    Sample1    6   3500
root    home    Sample1    7   8500
root    home    Sample1    8   2200
```

**Sub DF (2nd iteration of loop)**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name  ID  Value2
root    home    Sample2    1   5000
root    home    Sample2    2   9000
root    home    Sample2    3   700
root    home    Sample2    5   400
root    home    Sample2    6   3500
root    home    Sample2    7   8500
root    home    Sample2    8   2200
```

**Sub DF (3rd iteration of loop)**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name  ID  Value2
root    home    Sample3    1   5000
root    home    Sample3    2   9000
root    home    Sample3    5   400
root    home    Sample3    6   3500
root    home    Sample3    7   8500
root    home    Sample3    8   2200
```

**ACTUAL Updated Main DF (After iterating through the 3 SubDF's)**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name   ID   Value1   Value2
root    home    Sample1     1    1        5000
root    home    Sample1     2    0        9000
root    home    Sample1     7    1        8500
root    home    Sample2     1    0        5000   
root    home    Sample2     2    1        9000
root    home    Sample2     3    1        700 
root    home    Sample2     8    1        8800
root    home    Sample3     1    0        5000 
root    home    Sample3     2    1        9000
root    home    Sample3     6    1        3500
```

**DESIRED Updated Main DF**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name   ID   Value1   Value2
root    home    Sample1     1    1        5000
root    home    Sample1     2    0        9000
root    home    Sample1     5    1        400
root    home    Sample1     6    1        3500
root    home    Sample1     7    0        8500
root    home    Sample1     8    0        2200
root    home    Sample2     1    0        5000
root    home    Sample2     2    1        9000
root    home    Sample2     3    1        700
root    home    Sample2     5    0        400
root    home    Sample2     6    0        3500
root    home    Sample2     7    0        8500
root    home    Sample2     8    1        2200
root    home    Sample3     1    0        5000
root    home    Sample3     2    1        9000
root    home    Sample3     5    0        400
root    home    Sample3     6    1        3500
root    home    Sample3     7    0        8500
root    home    Sample3     8    0        2200
```

Comment: @chinsoon12 That's a first! I need to update a table by adding an additional column and rows that don't currently exist, and then continue updating that table with successive tables of the same format of the first.

Comment: @chinsoon12 In my block titled "Current Code", there is a section marked out called "Code in Question".  That code is performing a left join on the tables, but I need a full join in order to add the rows from the right table that don't exist in the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, this should be what you are looking for:

```
rbindlist(list(Sub_DF1, Sub_DF2, Sub_DF3))[
    Main_DF, on=.(Path1, Path2, File_Name, ID), Value1 := i.Value1][
        is.na(Value1), Value1 := 0L][]
```

output:

```
    Path1 Path2 File_Name ID Value2 Value1
 1:  root  home   Sample1  1   5000      1
 2:  root  home   Sample1  2   9000      0
 3:  root  home   Sample1  5    400      0
 4:  root  home   Sample1  6   3500      0
 5:  root  home   Sample1  7   8500      1
 6:  root  home   Sample1  8   2200      0
 7:  root  home   Sample2  1   5000      0
 8:  root  home   Sample2  2   9000      1
 9:  root  home   Sample2  3    700      1
10:  root  home   Sample2  5    400      0
11:  root  home   Sample2  6   3500      0
12:  root  home   Sample2  7   8500      0
13:  root  home   Sample2  8   2200      1
14:  root  home   Sample3  1   5000      0
15:  root  home   Sample3  2   9000      1
16:  root  home   Sample3  5    400      0
17:  root  home   Sample3  6   3500      1
18:  root  home   Sample3  7   8500      0
19:  root  home   Sample3  8   2200      0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
Main_DF <- fread("Path1   Path2   File_Name   ID   Value1
root    home    Sample1     1    1
root    home    Sample1     2    0
root    home    Sample1     7    1
root    home    Sample2     1    0
root    home    Sample2     2    1
root    home    Sample2     3    1
root    home    Sample2     8    1
root    home    Sample3     1    0
root    home    Sample3     2    1
root    home    Sample3     6    1")

Sub_DF1 <- fread("Path1   Path2   File_Name  ID  Value2
root    home    Sample1    1   5000
root    home    Sample1    2   9000
root    home    Sample1    5   400
root    home    Sample1    6   3500
root    home    Sample1    7   8500
root    home    Sample1    8   2200")

Sub_DF2 <- fread("Path1   Path2   File_Name  ID  Value2
root    home    Sample2    1   5000
root    home    Sample2    2   9000
root    home    Sample2    3   700
root    home    Sample2    5   400
root    home    Sample2    6   3500
root    home    Sample2    7   8500
root    home    Sample2    8   2200")

Sub_DF3 <- fread("Path1   Path2   File_Name  ID  Value2
root    home    Sample3    1   5000
root    home    Sample3    2   9000
root    home    Sample3    5   400
root    home    Sample3    6   3500
root    home    Sample3    7   8500
root    home    Sample3    8   2200")
```

Comment: The problem is that the subdf's are generated in a loop, so they only exist one at a time. And if I stored all of them, and then did the rbind, I would be trying to rbind 50 dataframes of 50,000 rows each. (That may be what I ultimately have to do, but I think I've done something similar and it was quite slow.)

Comment: i think if you rbind one table at a time, it should be slower as it takes time to allocate the memory each time.

Comment: Are you saying to use the rbind, but with the one list inside of the loop? (instead of the three df's you have in it now?)

Comment: you can assign your results of a list of data.tables before using the code above e.g. `l <- lapply(1:3, function(n) your_code_returning_data.table)` then `rbindlist(l)`

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't the implementation I was looking for, but @chinsoon12 solution works in a different way.

In the loop that processes the SubDF's, i assign the rbind to a new dataframe. I then push that smaller dataframe to my database before the loop recycles, overwriting the dataframe with the next SubDF data.

This was one of the avenues I had planned on looking at if I couldn't get the data.table join to work the way I was hoping.

Thanks for the help!